# In the context of registering a new user to my User Pool what is my IdentityPoolID?

Tags: javascript, debugging, amazon-web-services

I'm so stuck and frustrated. In the following link showing how to use Javascript SDK to register a new user to a user pool you will see:

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: '...' // your identity pool id here
});

AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWSCognito.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: '...' // your identity pool id here
});
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples-confirm-registration

Yet I can't see to find anything in my AWS console Cognito area that calls itself by the name IdentityPoolId, making me unsure what I am supposed to enter for the IdentityPoolId field. If i enter a random string like '1234' as the IdentitiyPoolId I get the following error pop up:

```
ValidationException: Missing credentials in config
```

But if I put in something like:

```
us-east-1:758097645222
```

I get this error:

```
ResourceNotFoundException: Missing credentials in config
```

What am I meant to be entering as my identityPoolId, where can I find it and what is the source of these two different errors?!

Thanks

Comment: Still stuck guys. Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To get an identity pool id you should use the "Manage Federated Identities" parts of the Cognito console not the "Manage User Pools" section

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37224093/1198079