# Why do AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.getAdminUser and AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.listUsers return task.result that is nil?

Tags: amazon-cognito

AWS Cognito is integrated into my Swift app and logins work.  However, when I try to use the AWSCognitoIdentityProvider api, the returned `task.result` is nil.  Why?  Here is the code:

```
let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.default()
let poolId = pool.userPoolConfiguration.poolId

let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId:poolId)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

let aguReq = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAdminGetUserRequest()
aguReq?.userPoolId = poolId
aguReq?.username = "USERNAME_GOES_HERE"

let luReq = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersRequest()
luReq?.userPoolId = poolId

let acpDefault = AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.default()
acpDefault.adminGetUser(aguReq!).continueWith(block: { (task: AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAdminGetUserResponse>) -> Any? in
  task.result?.userAttributes?.forEach({ (attr: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAttributeType) in
    let attrName = attr.name
    let attrValue = attr.value
    print("attrName=\(String(describing: attrName)); attrValue=\(String(describing: attrValue))")
  })
  return nil
})

acpDefault.listUsers(luReq!).continueWith(block: { (task: AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersResponse>) -> Any? in
  task.result?.users?.forEach({ (u: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderUserType) in
    print("username=\(String(describing: u.username))")
  })
  return nil
})
```

`Info.plist` references all of the key properties for Cognito.  Is it possible that `listUsers` and `adminGetUser` are reserved in some way?

Also, for the USERNAME_GOES_HERE stub, I always place a Cognito `username`, but not a Cognito ID or sub UUID.  Does that work?  (It seems odd that the `username` is required, since I thought in Cognito that `username` is not necessarily unique across Cognito users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AdminGetUser and ListUsers are APIs which should be accessed from you backend and the calls must present valid IAM credentials.

You should not be calling these APIs from your iOS app. Instead use [iOS Mobile SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/walkthrough-using-the-ios-sdk.html) methods which will allows your users to sign in and then call the appropriate Cognito User Pools APIs.

As to why your calls fail, it seems you are trying to provide required IAM credentials using the Federated Identity service temporary credentials. You are instantiating the credential provider with identity pool but passing the user pool id instead of identity pool id. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223695/aws-cognito-error-identitypoolid-failed-to-satisfy-constraint/37224093#37224093) for more explanation.

Comment: If those are backend APIs, how can a frontend client get the "sub" UUID?