# Get roles associated with user pool - AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Once the user logs into Cognito, I would like a lambda function to get the current role associated with that user.

It seems like Cognito User pools or Identity pools are to be used with mobile apps, and front end dev?

What is the correct way of doing this? Code examples are always nice, but I'm more looking for a logical solution, or links to documentation.

I tried out **AmazonCognitoIdentity** (which was not what I was looking for) and read all(?) documentation around this matter but I'm not able to connect the dots here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Cognito Error: 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223695/aws-cognito-error-identitypoolid-failed-to-satisfy-constraint)

Comment: @helloV It was at first, but I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Check the question hellov linked. There are two things here, you are using GetIdentityPoolRolesRequest which targets Cognito Federated Identities and gets you the roles associated with an identity pool. It seems you want to get the roles associated with a Cognito User Pool which is completely different.

Comment: Ah there are two pools. It was either CognitoIdentity or CognitoSync. I will look into the other question.